# Finding the area of a circular sector

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The central angle of the sector is $80$ degrees and the radius of the circle is 8.

I went ahead and converted the central angle measurement into radians which gave me $\frac { 4\pi }{ 9 } $

I put in all my known values into the formula $A=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } r^{ 2 }\Theta $

$A=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } 8^{ 2 }\frac { 4\pi }{ 9 } $

and this came out to $A=\frac { 128\pi }{ 9 }$

This is simplified to $\approx 44.68$ but the answer is $35.45$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Nowhere!  Your answer is right.

Comment: I hate these textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the formula for degrees:
$$\frac{r^2n\pi}{360^o}$$
Using your values $r=8$ and $n=80^o$:
$$\frac{8^280^o\pi}{360^o}$$
$$\frac{128\pi}{9}$$
The same result as you got, so your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right. Its (80/360)*pi*8^2 which gives area as 44.6577